# C++ pointer explanation

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
char* pstr[] = { "Robert Redford", // Initializing a pointer array
                 "Hopalong Cassidy",
                 "Lassie",
                 "Slim Pickens",
                 "Boris Karloff",
                 "Oliver Hardy"
               };
```

If I write like below:

```
*pstr[0] = 'X';
```

The program can compile but crashes when this statement is executed. Why? I thought *pstr[0] is 'R' so that I can change from 'R' to 'X'.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler should have warned you:

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*''
```

What you're doing here is assigning some constant char arrays to a mutable char pointer, much like:

```
const char[] astring = "ababa";
char* mutablestring = astring; // shouldn't be possible
mutablestring[0] = 'o'; // change 'readonly' location
```

The result is, at run time, a pointer that points into your binary, and that you're writing to.  But that's readonly memory, so.. crash.

Comment: Starting with C++11, the compiler may treat the conversion as an error.

Answer (score 7):

You are making a pointer to an array of `const char*`s. So pstr[0] is pointing to a `const char*` and you can't change it's value.

It's a good programming practice to write this code in this way so you'll get a compiler error if you try to change the value instead of runtime error:

```
char* const pstr[] = { "Robert Redford", // Initializing a pointer array
                 "Hopalong Cassidy",
                 "Lassie",
                 "Slim Pickens",
                 "Boris Karloff",
                 "Oliver Hardy"
               };
```

Comment: +1 for a good answer. You may also use `std::string` to ease your work.

Comment: String literals are of type `char *` formally for historical reasons, which is why it compiles, but are actually immutable.

Comment: The `const` should be on the other side of the asterisk, your example will still compile things such as `**pstr = 'Q'`.

Answer (score 2):

The string literals are constants, so you cannot change them.

Conversion from `const char*` to `char*` is allowed just to allow old C code from the time before C got `const`.

Answer (score 2):

`pstr` is an array with `const *char` elements. The result of modifying read-only memory is undefined. If you know the max size of each string you can declare `pstr` like so

```
char pstr[][32] = { "Robert Redford",
                 "Hopalong Cassidy",
                 "Lassie",
                 "Slim Pickens",
                 "Boris Karloff",
                 "Oliver Hardy"
               };
```